# Webstrom - тормозит удаленная отладка

Tags: отладка, webstorm

в WebStorm тормозит удаленная отладка, т.е. при  ctrl + s, долго грузится сохранение на сервере, но так не всегда, через раз, через два, также работаю на другом компьютере где все летает при аналогично настроенном ПО.

Comment: по всей видимости открывается соединение с удаленным сервером, вот и тормозит

Comment: Ну такое ведь на других компьютерах не происходит, долгая загрузка на сервер, разница в скорости 1мбит, на одном 5мб на проблемном 4мб.